# How is death "romanticized"?

Tags: american-english, literature, poetry, literary-techniques

Many times in question papers we can see that there's a question on "how death is romanticized in *xxxx* poem/ story?"

My question is how do we determine that the writer has romanticized death or suicide, what are the indications?

Comment: Hello and welcome! This question is really broad and difficult to answer as stated. It also might be better suited for the [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), as the root of your question is something like, "How do we know that something is being romanticized in literature?"